# 0x800f0831 Activating Windows Server 2016 from trial to standard

Tags: windows-server-2016, activation

for some reason i cannot activate windows server 2016 from evalution to standard with the standard activation through settings it post error that this version cannot be upgraded. 
With powershell script im getting error 0x800F083. I Also i cannot unninstal or install any system language getting the  0x800F0831 error also. Tried it with the lpksetup. Tried installing all the updates but nothing worked. Ive activated over 100 servers with the same configuration only on two of them have this issue they have exactly the same updates and configuration

Any suggestions? 
Logs

```
  PS C:\Users\Administrator> Dism /online /Set-Edition:ServerStandard /AcceptEula /ProductKey:

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.3241

Image Version: 10.0.14393.3241

Starting to update components...


Finished installing product key.

Removing package Microsoft-Windows-ServerStandardEvalEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0
[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f0831

An error occurred while operating system components were being updated. The upgrade cannot proceed.
For more information, review the log file.
```

sfc scan

```
    C:\Users\Administrator.MLADA-BOLESLAV>sfc /scannow

    Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

    Beginning verification phase of system scan.
    Verification 100% complete.

    Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
    of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
    example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
    supported in offline servicing scenarios.

cbs 

    2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d0b@2020/1/31:13:04:04.084 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d0c@2020/1/31:13:04:04.091 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d0d@2020/1/31:13:04:04.109 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d0e@2020/1/31:13:04:04.118 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d0f@2020/1/31:13:04:04.125 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d10@2020/1/31:13:04:04.148 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d11@2020/1/31:13:04:04.156 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d12 [SR] Verify complete
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d13 [SR] Verifying 2 components
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d14 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d15@2020/1/31:13:04:04.178 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d16@2020/1/31:13:04:04.186 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d17 [SR] Verify complete
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d18 [SR] Repairing 2 components
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d19 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d1a Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-m..nlevelmanifests-net_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.2457_none_f7ac929c132a948a\RasMigPlugin.dll do not match actual file [l:16]'RasMigPlugin.dll' :
  Found: {l:32 WO5snddkICOeygwvraeHow1XlnPJjrWXP2VjiTdYq14=} Expected: {l:32 nC8pNV6MVYWRCZ9+zJ+DHcoaHLyYbXyA9nw6LLPSZro=}
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d1b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:16]'RasMigPlugin.dll' of Microsoft-Windows-Migration-DownlevelManifests-net, version 10.0.14393.2457, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d1c@2020/1/31:13:04:04.205 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d1d Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-m..nlevelmanifests-net_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.2457_none_f7ac929c132a948a\RasMigPlugin.dll do not match actual file [l:16]'RasMigPlugin.dll' :
  Found: {l:32 WO5snddkICOeygwvraeHow1XlnPJjrWXP2VjiTdYq14=} Expected: {l:32 nC8pNV6MVYWRCZ9+zJ+DHcoaHLyYbXyA9nw6LLPSZro=}
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d1e [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:16]'RasMigPlugin.dll' of Microsoft-Windows-Migration-DownlevelManifests-net, version 10.0.14393.2457, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d1f [SR] This component was referenced by [l:80]'Package_3865_for_KB4534307~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.6.4534307-6682_neutral'
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d20 Hashes for file member \??\C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\dlmanifests\Microsoft-Windows-RasServer-MigPlugin\RasMigPlugin.dll do not match actual file [l:16]'RasMigPlugin.dll' :
  Found: {l:32 WO5snddkICOeygwvraeHow1XlnPJjrWXP2VjiTdYq14=} Expected: {l:32 nC8pNV6MVYWRCZ9+zJ+DHcoaHLyYbXyA9nw6LLPSZro=}
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d21 Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-m..nlevelmanifests-net_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.2457_none_f7ac929c132a948a\RasMigPlugin.dll do not match actual file [l:16]'RasMigPlugin.dll' :
  Found: {l:32 WO5snddkICOeygwvraeHow1XlnPJjrWXP2VjiTdYq14=} Expected: {l:32 nC8pNV6MVYWRCZ9+zJ+DHcoaHLyYbXyA9nw6LLPSZro=}
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d22 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file \??\C:\Windows\System32\migwiz\dlmanifests\Microsoft-Windows-RasServer-MigPlugin\RasMigPlugin.dll; source file in store is also corrupted
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d23@2020/1/31:13:04:04.318 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d24 Hashes for file member \??\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Server Manager.lnk do not match actual file [l:18]'Server Manager.lnk' :
  Found: {l:32 5CDB5YBG9xrE5jYfiQKBjrHde4kkc32DcLsTjvM926k=} Expected: {l:32 BL5+MEWIW/CPxiRm/2a5O9gB4dywyki2bd/5ufR7wCA=}
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d25 [SR] Repairing corrupted file \??\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Server Manager.lnk from store
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d26@2020/1/31:13:04:04.333 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d27 [SR] Repair complete
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d28 [SR] Committing transaction
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d29 Creating NT transaction (seq 13), objectname '(null)'
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d2a Created NT transaction (seq 13) result 0x00000000, handle @0x1da9c
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d2b@2020/1/31:13:04:04.499 Beginning NT transaction commit...
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d2c@2020/1/31:13:04:04.510 CSI perf trace:
CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;13503
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CSI    00008d2d [SR] Verify and Repair Transaction completed. All files and registry keys listed in this transaction  have been successfully repaired
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CBS    Disabling LKG boot option
2020-01-31 14:04:04, Info                  CBS    Exec: Creating restore point: Package: Microsoft-Windows-ServerStandardEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0, current: Staged, targeted: Staged

   DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 GetTargetEditions: Successfully retrieved edition targets for [ServerDatacenter] from [ServerDatacenter]. - CTransmogManager::GetTargetEditions
2020-01-31 13:57:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 GetTargetEditions: Successfully retrieved edition targets for [ServerDatacenter] from [ServerStandard]. - CTransmogManager::GetTargetEditions
2020-01-31 13:57:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 GetTargetEditions: Successfully retrieved edition targets for [ServerDatacenter] from [ServerStandardEval]. - CTransmogManager::GetTargetEditions
2020-01-31 13:57:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 RemoveUnavailableEditions: Retrieved target edition collection. - CTransmogManager::RemoveUnavailableEditions
2020-01-31 13:57:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 RemoveUnavailableEditions: Target Edition Count: [1] - CTransmogManager::RemoveUnavailableEditions
2020-01-31 13:57:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 RemoveUnavailableEditions: Skipping EditionId [ServerDatacenter]. - CTransmogManager::RemoveUnavailableEditions
2020-01-31 13:57:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 RemoveUnavailableEditions: Skipping target EditionId [ServerStandard]. - CTransmogManager::RemoveUnavailableEditions
2020-01-31 13:57:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 RemoveUnavailableEditions: Unavailable Edition Count: [1] - CTransmogManager::RemoveUnavailableEditions
2020-01-31 13:57:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 RemoveUnavailableEditions: Successfully removed unavailable editions. - CTransmogManager::RemoveUnavailableEditions
2020-01-31 13:57:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 Processing package changes... - CTransmogManager::UpdateComponents
2020-01-31 13:57:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 Processing package changes with options [0x3]... - CTransmogManager::UpdateComponents
2020-01-31 13:57:55, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=19620 TID=31976 CBS session options=0x540! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2020-01-31 14:09:46, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=19620 TID=29088  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x800f0831) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
2020-01-31 14:09:46, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=19620 TID=31976 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f0831)
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=19620 TID=31976 Failed processing package changes with session options - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChangesWithOptions(hr:0x800f0831)
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 Package manager failed to process changes - CTransmogManager::UpdateComponents(hr:0x800f0831)
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 Failed to update components - CTransmogManager::UpdateComponents(hr:0x800f0831)
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 Failed to update components from [ServerStandardEval] to [ServerStandard] - CTransmogManager::TransmogrifyWorker
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 [Upgrading system]: An error occurred while operating system components were being updated. The upgrade cannot proceed.
For more information, review the log file.


 [hrError=0x800f0831] - CTransmogManager::EventError
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 Failed to Upgrade! - CTransmogManager::TransmogrifyWorker(hr:0x800f0831)
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Error                 DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=19620 TID=31976 Failed to upgrade! - CTransmogManager::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f0831)
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Found the PE Provider.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Package Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing CBS core. - CDISMPackageManager::Finalize
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(MsiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: MsiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(IntlManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: IntlManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(IBSManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: IBSManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(DriverManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: DriverManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Unattend Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Unattend Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(SmiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: SmiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(AppxManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: AppxManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(ProvManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: ProvManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(AssocManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: AssocManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(GenericManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: GenericManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(OfflineSetupManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: OfflineSetupManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Finalizing the servicing provider(Edition Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: Edition Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Releasing the local reference to OSServices. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Disconnecting Provider: OSServices - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=19620 TID=31976 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=39532 TID=6000 Closing session event handle 0x178 - CDISMManager::CloseImageSession
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=39532 TID=6000 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=39532 TID=6000 Disconnecting Provider: FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-01-31 14:09:47, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=39532 TID=6000 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
```

sfc scan log

```
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008320@2020/2/24:18:25:25.680 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008321@2020/2/24:18:25:25.688 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008322@2020/2/24:18:25:25.696 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008323 [SR] Verify complete
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008324 [SR] Repairing 1 components
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008325 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008326 Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..teconnectionmanager_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_bc13ad436af6bbc9\termsrv.dll do not match actual file [l:11]'termsrv.dll' :
  Found: {l:32 kRwLQZrGjsU14L760WEqhAqiJ0UhWDTfQh8QBBtK2ic=} Expected: {l:32 rDHYQf6li3dhJ+E42yD41I4m/YwAzi+paV6hTr8Vmgo=}
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008327 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:11]'termsrv.dll' of Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager, version 10.0.14393.0, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008328@2020/2/24:18:25:25.711 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008329 Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..teconnectionmanager_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_bc13ad436af6bbc9\termsrv.dll do not match actual file [l:11]'termsrv.dll' :
  Found: {l:32 kRwLQZrGjsU14L760WEqhAqiJ0UhWDTfQh8QBBtK2ic=} Expected: {l:32 rDHYQf6li3dhJ+E42yD41I4m/YwAzi+paV6hTr8Vmgo=}
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    0000832a [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:11]'termsrv.dll' of Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager, version 10.0.14393.0, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    0000832b [SR] This component was referenced by [l:129]'Microsoft-Windows-Server-Features-Remainder-termsrv-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0.241c8d7eec805723b67b8d29e1755dca'
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    0000832c [SR] This component was referenced by [l:129]'Microsoft-Windows-ServerCore-SKU-Foundation-termsrv-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0.88ba03d966adfa5b689c0042a4cd98b3'
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    0000832d [SR] This component was referenced by [l:169]'Microsoft-Windows-Server-Features-Package-AutoMerged-termsrv~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0.Microsoft-Windows-Server-Features-Package-AutoMerged-termsrv-Deployment'
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    0000832e [SR] This component was referenced by [l:106]'Microsoft-Windows-TS-termsrv-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0.f0d406315b6d7c71a135b8c6def8e62f'
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    0000832f Hashes for file member \??\C:\Windows\System32\termsrv.dll do not match actual file [l:11]'termsrv.dll' :
  Found: {l:32 kRwLQZrGjsU14L760WEqhAqiJ0UhWDTfQh8QBBtK2ic=} Expected: {l:32 rDHYQf6li3dhJ+E42yD41I4m/YwAzi+paV6hTr8Vmgo=}
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008330 Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..teconnectionmanager_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_bc13ad436af6bbc9\termsrv.dll do not match actual file [l:11]'termsrv.dll' :
  Found: {l:32 kRwLQZrGjsU14L760WEqhAqiJ0UhWDTfQh8QBBtK2ic=} Expected: {l:32 rDHYQf6li3dhJ+E42yD41I4m/YwAzi+paV6hTr8Vmgo=}
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008331 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file \??\C:\Windows\System32\termsrv.dll; source file in store is also corrupted
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008332@2020/2/24:18:25:25.732 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008333 [SR] Repair complete
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008334 [SR] Committing transaction
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008335 Creating NT transaction (seq 1), objectname '(null)'
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008336 Created NT transaction (seq 1) result 0x00000000, handle @0x13dc
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008337@2020/2/24:18:25:25.758 Beginning NT transaction commit...
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008338@2020/2/24:18:25:25.765 CSI perf trace:
CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;9156
2020-02-24 19:25:25, Info                  CSI    00008339 [SR] Verify and Repair Transaction completed. All files and registry keys listed in this transaction  have been successfully repaired
```

Comment: It sounds like hacking software to me...

Comment: Hi, is it a OEM license you tried ? and is it a demo in a highter version you tried ? Just to be sure you didnt tried a datacenter demo, as downgrading can be a problem

Comment: oem license yes i tried to call microsoft support but i got connected with some indian guy i could not understand him a single word